# MS Access Nz() Function not Recognised in MS Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write an expression in MS Access which returns a string of text, `"New Policy"`, in the `Iif()` statement after it returns an error.
When I export the data from Access into Excel it tells me that `Nz()` is not recognised.
Is there an alternative to this function? My Access expression is as follows:

```
Nz(IIf([Policy Status]=[Input - WFAC Previous Day]![Policy Status 1],"Remains " & [Policy Status],[Input - WFAC Previous Day]![Policy Status 1] & " to " & [Policy Status]), "New Policy")
```

Comment: You're correct - `NZ` doesn't exist in Excel. How are you trying to use it in Excel?  If you're exporting the data to Excel surely it's just data with no formula attached? The posted code looks like it's referencing form controls or maybe fields but they don't translate to Excel cell references.

Comment: To return a string of text after an error you'd use something like `=IFERROR($A$1,"New Policy")`, but that doesn't translate to the code you've posted.

Answer (score 6):

`Nz` is defined in the Microsoft Access type library, which is automatically referenced when your host application is, well, Access.

If you add a reference to the Access type library in your Excel project, you should be able to use `Nz`... but then your Excel project won't work if Access isn't installed, which is... weird and rather heavy-handed.

What does `Nz` do? Looks like some kind of `Coalesce` function that should be rather trivial to implement on your own and customize as needed. Something like this?

```
Public Function Coalesce(ByVal value As Variant, Optional ByVal value_when_null As Variant = 0) As Variant

    Dim return_value As Variant
    On Error Resume Next 'supress error handling

    If IsEmpty(value) Or IsNull(value) Or (VarType(value) = vbString And value = vbNullString) Then
        return_value = value_when_null
    Else
        return_value = value
    End If

    Err.Clear 'clear any errors that might have occurred
    On Error GoTo 0 'reinstate error handling

    Coalesce = return_value

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Nz for this:

```
IIf(IsNull([Policy Status]), "New Policy",
IIf([Policy Status] & "" = [Input - WFAC Previous Day]![Policy Status 1],
"Remains " & [Policy Status],
 [Input - WFAC Previous Day]![Policy Status 1] & " to " & [Policy Status]))
```

Comment: As is the case for any function, the arguments given to `IIf` need to be evaluated before they're passed to the function... looks like if policy status is null, the result can't be evaluated..

Comment: Yes @MathieuGuindon, but that's what this expression does with IsNull. In the next part, a potential Null is concatenated with "" to never return Null.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VBA, you can add a Reference to the MS Access library, e.g. "Microsoft Access 14.0 object library. Then the `Nz` function is available as `Access.Nz(value, "New Policy")`. You could even create a user-defined function for use on Excel spreadsheets:

```
Public Function Nz(Value As Variant, Optional ValueIfNull As Variant = "New Policy") As Variant
    Nz = Access.Nz(Value, ValueIfNull)
End Function
```

Hope that helps